# Can you decipher what this seal stamp says and means?

Tags: meaning, characters, seal

I am told that this seal stamp character(s) are from the Chinese dialect, though I got it from my Japanese grandmother.  She had it made and gave it to me. I was told it says 'strong and smart' and also resembles my name 'Matthew'.

I have not been able to find the characters that are shown on the stamp, and do not know either language well. Can someone help me with what the characters say and mean, or where to find them, along with anything else?

[image]

Comment: The stamp with seal scripts of Chinese reads `麥菲` (mài fēi), which indeed transliterates "Matthew", but I don't get the "strong and smart" point.

Comment: The text shown on the stamp is ancient Chinese writing, it is literally called "JiaGu Text" in China. In modern times, even most people in China doesn't know how to decipher these writings, except historians and old-text inspector. Don't worry about what it says, it should be a phrase or word used in ancient China.

Comment: Not JiaGu script (oracle script), precisely it should be called 缪篆 or 摹印篆.

Comment: This is obviously 篆文，not 甲骨文.

Comment: Neither 麦 nor 菲 has the meaning of "strong and smart" in Chinese. 麦means _wheat_, 菲 usually uses as an adjective to describe plants(grass) growing well.

Comment: If a person manage to learn 篆文, he/she is definitely strong and smart spiritually.

Answer (score 2):

The the characters on the stamp were written in 小篆(xiao zhuan), which is an ancient Chinese writing form. The character on the right is 麥, which means wheat. The character on the left is 菲, which means the fragrance of plants. I don't know how those two characters could relate to 'strong and smart'. I think the combination of the two characters might have a specific meaning in Japanese, since there are also Chinese characters in Japanese.

Comment: No, there's not specific meaning in Japanese.